# netmiko script connexion router

Tags: python, paramiko, cisco, netmiko

When I run my *Python* script, I get errors on the *paramiko library*...

But the result of the script is not understanding.Can anyone help with this issue..!?

Here is the **Error**:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2044, in _check_banner
    buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 353, in readline
    buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 540, in _read_timeout
    x = self.__socket.recv(128)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

During handling of the above exception, I  got another exception

Here is the **new Exception**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1893, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2049, in _check_banner
    'Error reading SSH protocol banner' + str(e)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Script run time = 00:02:34**
```

**Here is the script**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
#import ipaddress
import csv
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile,join,expanduser
import getpass
import threading
import logging
import re
import time
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from netmiko.ssh_exception import NetMikoTimeoutException
from netmiko.ssh_exception import NetMikoAuthenticationException

#-----------------------------------------------------------
def get_wd():
    wd = os.path.expanduser('temp/')
    if not os.path.exists(wd):
        os.makedirs(wd)
    return wd
#-----------------------------------------------------------
def del_temp_files():
    list_temp_dir = os.listdir(wd)
    ext = (".json",".csv",".txt",".log")
    for item in list_temp_dir:
        if item.endswith(ext):
            os.remove(os.path.join(wd, item))


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def ssh_connection(ip, ref, username, password):
    try:
        return ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios',ip=ip,username=username,password=password)
    except Exception as error:
        logger.error('. %&%&%&%&%& {} {}   \t   {}'.format(ref, ip, error))
        with open ("{}conn_error.txt".format(wd), "a") as efile:
            efile.write('{} {} \n'.format(ref, ip))
#--------------------envoie de commande et stocker le resultat dans un fichier----------------------------------------------------
def get_worker(ip, ref, device):
    try:
        result = device.send_command("show run | inc username")
        if "cisco" in result:
            usert="yes"
        else:
            usert="no"
        with open ("{}result.csv".format(wd), "a") as file1:
            file1.write('{} {}\n'.format(ref,usert))
    except Exception as error:
        logger.error(". Get Error  {}  {}   \t    {}".format(ref, ip, error))
#-----------------------connection aux équipements--------------------------------------------------------
def main(ip, ref, username, password):
    device = ssh_connection(ip, ref, username, password)
    if device == None:
            sema.release()
            return
    output = get_worker(ip, ref, device)
    device.disconnect()
    sema.release()
if __name__ == '__main__':

    wd = get_wd()
    del_temp_files()
    threads = []
    max_threads = 20
    sema = threading.BoundedSemaphore(value=max_threads)
    user = "cisco"
    passwd = "cisco"

    start_time = time.time()
    logger = logging.getLogger("LOG")
    handler = logging.FileHandler("{}main.log".format(wd))
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
with open("/home/net/inventaire_routes/cisco.csv.save") as fh:
    devices = csv.reader(fh,delimiter=';')
    for host in devices:
        sema.acquire()
        ip = host[1]
        ref = host[0]
        thread = threading.Thread(target=main, args=(ip, ref, user, passwd))
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print("Script run time = " + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(elapsed_time)))
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I resolve this issue..!??

Comment: Can you do even plain Paramiko connection to one device and execute one command?

Comment: but I use the netmiko library I do not understand why I have this error

Comment: Netmiko uses Paramiko internally.  We need [mcve].

Comment: you want me to make a simple connection without threading just with the netmiko library?

Comment: Just with Paramiko library.

Comment: I post  just minimal reproducible example, I still have paramiko errors!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('192.16.16.2', username= 'admin', password= 'cisco')

stdin, stdout, stderr =ssh.exec_command("show run | inc username ")
output = stdout.readlines()
print('\n'.join(output))
ssh.close()






username admin privilege 15 password 7 00071A150754

Exception ignored in: <object repr() failed>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 66, in __del__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1392, in close
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 991, in shutdown_write
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 963, in shutdown
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1246, in _send_eof
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/message.py", line 232, in add_int
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: What is this? This does not look like an answer.